# convert second order coupled equations to first order

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I want to convert the coupled differential equation to a system of first-order differential equations, Is it possible. Can anybody help me?

$$\begin{bmatrix}
A & B\\
B & E 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}\ddot{y}\\ \ddot{x} \end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}C & 0\\0&F \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}{y}\\ {x} \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}D\\ G \end{bmatrix}$$
where $y$ and $x$ are the dependent variables.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Introduce the variables $x = x_1$, $\dot{x}=\dot{x}_1=x_2$ and $y = x_3$, $\dot{y}=\dot{x}_3=x_4$.

Your equations are

$$\dot{x}_1=x_2$$
$$\ddot{x}=\dot{x}_2=?$$
$$\dot{x}_3=x_4$$
$$\ddot{y}=\dot{x}_4=?$$

can you fill in the remaining equations?

---

As you system looks like a mechanical mass-spring system

$$\boldsymbol{M\ddot{q}}(t)+\boldsymbol{Kq}(t)=\boldsymbol{F}(t)$$

you can also use modal decomposition to turn the coupled second order system to an uncoupled second order system.

You will have to determine the eigenfrequencies $\omega_i$ by solving

$$\det\left[-\omega^2\boldsymbol{M}+\boldsymbol{K} \right]=0$$

and the eigenvectors $\hat{\boldsymbol{q}}$ by solving

$$\left[-\omega^2\boldsymbol{M}+\boldsymbol{K} \right]\hat{\boldsymbol{q}}=\boldsymbol{0}$$

In order to determine the uncoupled system, you can use the procedure from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2680563/modal-decoupling-of-differential-equations).

Comment: But this is what exactly I did. Since i have second derivative of x and y in the same equation, I get the first order equation in y interms of the first order derivative of x.

Comment: I do not understand your comment. You wanted to transform the system into a first order system and that is how it is done. If you want to decouple it you will have to determine the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the system matrix.

Comment: I added a method for decoupling the second order system into a second order system in modal coordinates.

Comment: Thanks. will try it out